# How do I open a grill ignitor?

Tags: high-voltage, spark

My grill rusted apart, so I decided to salvage the spark circuit.
But there's a problem - I can't find the polarity of the ports, and I can't open up the blackbox. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Ku3.jpg
How can I crack this open without breaking it, or alternatively, is there a way to figure out the polarity? All the exposed pins are outputs, and the wires lead to a switch.

Comment: There is nothing to crack open, the whole assembly is flooded with cured potting resin. It's like trying to crack open a brick.

Comment: Well, do you know how I can test the polarity then?

Comment: If it's just an ignitor, you sure it has a polarity? Those are usually pretty simple and have no need for being polarity specific. Only thing I could think is if it has polarity specific capacitors in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a standard "push button, goes clunk, get spark" type setup (can't tell from that picture), there's just a striker (somewhat like an automatic centerpunch) and a piezo disk inside it. You push the button, the striker strikes the piezo disk, the piezo disk makes volts (might well be AC as the crystal "rings" when struck, but I don't know, and I don't hate my oscilloscope enough to try and find out.) No electrical hanky-panky to speak of in one of those.

If it's some type of powered (110VAC - 230VAC - 9V?) unit, you'd have to supply more helpful information about how it WAS wired and powered than "all the pins are outputs and the wires go to a switch" which is pretty much no information at all.

If you wish to test the polarity, you'll need a resistor string able to take the output voltage, and you measure across one resistor on the ground end of the string - a voltage divider. That either needs some high voltage resistors or enough not-so-high voltage resistors in series that they add up to a high voltage. Odds are the resistors needed cost more than a 14 year old ignitor is worth.

Comment: It's powered. It runs on a single AA

Answer (score 0):

Your unit is most likely an electronic spark igniter. All such units that I have seen run from a single "AA" cell located either inside a port on the box **OR** housed within the push-button switch that operates the igniter.

The after-market igniters that I purchase from the Appliance Parts wholesaler have the push-button switch located on the box itself.  You install the battery by unscrewing the push-button plunger and sliding the "AA" cell inside.

I suppose that there is a polarity to the spark that comes from the unit but for its intended purpose of generating a spark, that polarity is irrelevant.